# Progress bar required while searching operation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Consider this is as either improvement or suggestion.

Currently if we write any term in search box (EditText) and click on DONE button from Keyboard and it goes for searching related QA contains that searched term.

But its taking time to search and user isn't getting notified with either any progress bar or any user friendly message that search is going on so please wait.

**Suggestion:**
It should show progress while searching and taking time to search and display result.

Comment: Maybe I'm spoiled by my internet speed, but is the search process really that slow that you need a progress bar?

Comment: No matter the internet speed, it should definitely have a indicator. You never know when someone's on EDGE and needs to search for something :)

Comment: Agree with Kasra. I am on 3G and still it sometimes takes time to fetch and load questions detail.

Comment: Fair point - I've been on EVDO (or better) for a while, so I forgot how slow EDGE can be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Added in as of version 0.1.45 coming out later tonight.

Comment: That was quick!