# App crashing issue - Pull to refresh question

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I just posted a [progress bar feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199076/progress-bar-required-while-searching-operation) question and I tried to pull to refresh it to get updates but app is getting closed, its not showing any force close dialog or anything informative.

FYI I tried checking and repeating this step for more than 10 mins.

**Update 1:**

And I have also tried the same process for [Notification with null:null value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198980/notification-with-nullnull-value) and the same app closing issue.

**Update 2:**

I tried checking this issue in latest version 0.1.45. This issue is not happening only while doing pull to refresh but it happens at many areas of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this bug was just left neglected, sorry about that. We switched over to a new pull-to-refresh library since and this should be fixed.